# Puppet removes cache/libs on the agent. Next run it through: "Error: Failed to apply catalog: Resource type 'Concat_file' was not found"

Tags: debugging, puppet

**Spec:**

Server:

- Puppet Server: 7.9.2 ([pupperware docker compose](https://github.com/puppetlabs/pupperware))
- a lot of custom modules

Agent:

- OS: CentOS7
- Puppet Agent: 7.25.0

**Problem:**

- When I run `puppet agent --test` on the target host first time it caches all libs and applies catalog well.
- Second run it removes all libs from `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib` and completes with error: `Error: Failed to apply catalog: Resource type 'Concat_file' was not found`
- Third time when I run puppet agent --test it does not restore libs as it should as per [the doc](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/dirs_vardir.html). As a result it failed to apply catalog: `Error: Failed to apply catalog: Resource type 'Concat_file' was not found`

**Done:**

- I am not able to find any related to this folder catalog configuration which has to cleanup this folder: `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib`.
- BUT I changed the main `./manifest/site.pp` on the puppet server to simple `info("DEBUG")` as a result `cache/lib` folder was NOT cleaned after second..3..10 run.
- Before first run I manually created `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib/puppet1` folder. During first run it was removed and all other folder were created.
- I have examined `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/client_data/catalog/lsv-vm259.rfiserve.net.json` after first run. No resource related to that folder.
- On puppet agent: `puppet resource file '/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib/puppet/type/concat_file.rb'`

  ```
  file { '/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib/puppet/type/concat_file.rb':
  ensure   => 'file',
  content  => '{sha256}cf7503aeaa145ccdb4d6fa898d1e71febf8ebec5fdb87847292474fc82f78d0a',
  ctime    => '2023-08-02 05:49:16 -0400',
  group    => 0,
  mode     => '0644',
  mtime    => '2023-08-02 05:49:16 -0400',
  owner    => 0,
  provider => 'posix',
  type     => 'file',
  }
  ```
- Second run I see:
  `Debug: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib/puppet]: Removing existing directory for replacement with absent
  Notice: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib/puppet]/ensure: removed
  Debug: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib/puppet]: The container /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib will propagate my refresh event
  Debug: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib/puppet/application]: Nothing to manage: no ensure and the resource doesn't exist`
- Also if I restart puppetserver, the cycle of "restore - removing cache" is repeated. In other words 'first and second' runs are in a sence of after puppetserver restart

**Puppet agent Debug logs:**

First run:
`Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Debug: Puppet::Network::Format[msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Debug: Puppet::Network::Format[rich_data_msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Debug: file_metadata supports formats: json pson yaml
Debug: Using cached connection for https://puppet-server:8140
Debug: HTTP GET https://puppet-server:8140/puppet/v3/file_metadatas/pluginfacts?recurse=true&max_files=-1&ignore=.s
vn&ignore=CVS&ignore=.git&ignore=.hg&links=follow&checksum_type=sha256&source_permissions=use&environment=production returne
d 200 OK
Debug: Caching connection for https://puppet-server:8140
Debug: Using cached connection for https://puppet-server:8140
Debug: HTTP GET https://puppet-server:8140/puppet/v3/file_content/pluginfacts/README?environment=production returne
d 200 OK
Debug: Caching connection for https://puppet-server:8140
Notice: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/facts.d/README]/ensure: defined content as '{sha256}9a0710ef5f5be42e1c7691efcf713
29c2f55e3e7483a0ae75144cc7792530990'
Debug: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/facts.d/README]: The container /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/facts.d will propagate my refresh event
Debug: Finishing transaction 11820`

Second run:
`Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Debug: Puppet::Network::Format[msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Debug: Puppet::Network::Format[rich_data_msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Debug: file_metadata supports formats: json pson yaml
Debug: Using cached connection for https://puppet-server:8140
Debug: HTTP GET https://puppet-server:8140/puppet/v3/file_metadatas/pluginfacts?recurse=true&max_files=-1&ignore=.s
vn&ignore=CVS&ignore=.git&ignore=.hg&links=follow&checksum_type=sha256&source_permissions=use&environment=production returne
d 200 OK
Debug: Caching connection for https://puppet-server:8140
Debug: Puppet::Network::Format[msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Debug: Puppet::Network::Format[rich_data_msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Debug: file_metadata supports formats: json pson yaml
Debug: Using cached connection for https://puppet-server:8140
Debug: HTTP GET https://puppet-server:8140/puppet/v3/file_metadata/pluginfacts?links=follow&checksum_type=sha256&so
urce_permissions=use&environment=production returned 200 OK
Debug: Caching connection for https://puppet-server:8140
Debug: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/facts.d/README]: Removing existing file for replacement with absent
Notice: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/facts.d/README]/ensure: removed
Debug: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/facts.d/README]: The container /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/facts.d will propagate my refresh event
Debug: Finishing transaction 11820`

Update 1:
It's easy to reproduce this issue with simple `manifest/site.pp` and `lib/puppet/functions/`:

`#cat ./lib/puppet/functions/brakepuppet.rb
require 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'`

#Documentation
Puppet::Functions.create_function(:brakepuppet) do
dispatch :brakepuppet do
required_param 'String', :print_text
end

def brakepuppet(print_text)
return $print_text
end
end

#cat ./manifest/site.pp
info("This is DEBUG")

file {
default:
ensure => 'file',
owner  => 'root',
group  => 'root',
mode   => '0644';
'/tmp/test.test':
content => brakepuppet("Print this text please");

commenting `require 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'` makes the difference.

Comment: The behavior you describe is unfamiliar to me.  The client and server versions you describe should be compatible, but perhaps there is an issue with the mismatch.  Is there any chance of upgrading Puppet to v7.25 on the server, or of downgrading it to v7.9 on the client?

Comment: My first guess is that the issue has something to do with the server having cached the client's catalog (hence the once-per-server-start behavior), but deleting the cached plugins is new and very strange to me.